# Migration to sbt 1: how to run Scalastyle at compilation time

Tags: sbt, sbt-plugin, scalastyle

I had scalastyle running at compilation time in my project. Since I updated from sbt 0.13 to sbt 1.0.1 I don't manage to make it work again.

I followed the documentation from [here](http://www.scalastyle.org/sbt.html) and added this to my build.sbt:

```
lazy val compileScalaStyle: TaskKey[Unit] = taskKey[Unit]("scalastyle")

compileScalastyle := scalastyle.in(Compile).toTask("").value,
(compile in Compile) := ((compile in Compile) dependsOn compileScalastyle).value,
```

But I get this error:
not found: value scalastyle

Do I need an import? If yes, I didn't manage to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not need a special import. There seems to be a typo in `compileScalaStyle`. Try

```
lazy val compileScalastyle = taskKey[Unit]("compileScalastyle")
```

instead of

```
lazy val compileScalaStyle: TaskKey[Unit] = taskKey[Unit]("scalastyle")
```

[Here](https://github.com/guardian/tip) is a working example project using Scalastyle 1.0.0 with SBT 1.0.4.